# I created Custom Part but now page numbers disappeared

Tags: formatting, page-numbering

Here is my code for

```
\newcommand\party[3]
{\clearpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{{#2}}\pagestyle{empty}

    \rule{0pt}{0.1\textheight}

    {\LARGE \bfseries\scshape \spaceout[2pt]{Part \:\:#1}}

    \vspace{2.5em}
    {\huge \bfseries\scshape\spaceout[1pt]{#2}}

\vspace{.7cm}
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.75\textwidth}
        #3
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}}
```

But when I compile the document I get the desired result for part page but for the next sections page numbers are gone. Attached in the pics.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps change `\pagestyle` to `\thispagestyle`

Comment: @daleif Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...